# How can I create a vertical resulting graph made of '*' symbols?

Tags: c

I should run a 10000 random dice rolling simulation with 1 dice only where at the end of each roll, you count and print the frequency of the resulting face value. Then, draw a bar graph of frequency versus face value made of ‘*’ symbols as shown below. The resulting graph will be close to a uniform distribution as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXmQo.png)

-Program output should be the same in shape to the program outputs above.
-I can only use “stdio.h, stdlib.h, time.h” function libraries.

```
/* 1. */

/* Libraries used for writing this code. */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

/* Rolling a six-sided dice 10000 times. */
int main()

{
    /*Counters for the number of times each face (1-6) is rolled. */
    int Times1 = 0;     
    int Times2 = 0; 
    int Times3 = 0;
    int Times4 = 0;
    int Times5 = 0;
    int Times6 = 0;

    int roll;   /* Roll counter for values from 1 to 10000 */
    int face;   /* One roll of the dice, value between 1 - 6 */

    srand( time(NULL) );    /* Changes the result for every run of the code. */

    for (roll = 1; roll <= 10000; roll++) {         /* Setting loop counter to 10000 */
        face = 1 + rand() % 6;                      /* Random value of dice after a roll, value between 1 - 6 */

        switch (face) {      /* Switch and case statement for the rolled face value counter. */

        case 1:
            ++Times1;
            break;

        case 2:
            ++Times2;
            break;

        case 3:
            ++Times3;
            break;

        case 4:
            ++Times4;
            break;

        case 5:
            ++Times5;
            break;

        case 6:
            ++Times6;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s%10s\n", "Dice", "Times");   /* Printing command the header for the result table */

    /* Printing commands for the each rolled face value. */
    printf("   1%10d\n", Times1);
    printf("   2%10d\n", Times2);
    printf("   3%10d\n", Times3);
    printf("   4%10d\n", Times4);
    printf("   5%10d\n", Times5);
    printf("   6%10d\n\n", Times6);

    /* Temporary variables to hold the number of times each face was rolled. */
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;
    int value4 = 0;
    int value5 = 0;
    int value6 = 0;
    
    /* Copy of the roll counts in temporary variables. */
    value1 = Times1;
    value2 = Times2;
    value3 = Times3;
    value4 = Times4;
    value5 = Times5;
    value6 = Times6;

    /* Variables for the number of asterisks printed for each face value. */
    int line1 = 0;
    int line2 = 0;
    int line3 = 0;
    int line4 = 0;
    int line5 = 0;
    int line6 = 0; 

    printf("1 ");   /* Command to print the label for the histogram. */ 
    
    /* While loop to print asterisks representing the number of times face value 1 was rolled. */
    while (line1 < value1) {
        printf("* ");
        line1 += 150;       /* Adjusting the value of each asterisks. */
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Same loop for the face values 2-6 */
    printf("2 ");

    while (line2 < value2) {
        printf("* ");
        line2 += 150;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("3 ");

    while (line3 < value3) {
        printf("* ");
        line3 += 150;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("4 ");

    while (line4 < value4) {
        printf("* ");
        line4 += 150;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("5 ");

    while (line5 < value5) {
        printf("* ");
        line5 += 150;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("6 ");

    while (line6 < value6) {
        printf("* ");
        line6 += 150;
    }
    return 0;   /* Indicates successful program termination. */

}       /* End of the main code. */
```

Comment: You may be using a C++ compiler to compile it, but this is just C.

Comment: Have you not learned about arrays yet? Figure out the largest value you have so you know how tall to make the graph. As you print each column compare the value for that column to the threshold for drawing an asterisk. If it is larger than the threshold print the asterisk otherwise print a space. Repeat for however many rows you need based on the largest value and whatever scale you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward if you use arrays. Consider an array of 3 values representing grades mapped on a graph 10 levels high.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int grades[] = {34, 76, 89};

    for (int level = 90; level >= 0; level -= 10) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(grades) / sizeof(grades[0]); i++) {
            if (grades[i] > level) {
                printf(" * ");
            }
            else {
                printf("   ");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output

```
       *
    *  *
    *  *
    *  *
    *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *  *
```

Your dice roll counts can be mapped to an array of 6 ints and the same approach used.